# How to arrange small size of excel rows (subset) according to large size of other excel rows?

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet with 500 rows and more than 10 columns. The first column is subject id. 
And I have list of subject id approximately contains 2000 id. The 500 id in the spreadsheet is subset of the external 2000 id.
I want to arrange the spreadsheet rows according to the external list of ids.

### Edit:

### I have spreadsheet 'A' of 500 rows

[image: This is the spreadsheet of 500 rows]

### and spreadsheet 'B' with 5000 rows

[image]

I want to edit spreadsheet 'A' by place its rows at the same position (row number) of its occurrence in 'B'.

In other words, you can see from above pictures that:

First subject of 'A' '2196978' is located in row number 2 in 'B'. My task is to put '2196978' of 'A' in row number 2

Second subject of 'A' '2219364' is located in row number 9 in 'B'. My task is to put '2219364' of 'A' in row number 9

and this is done by insert rows in 'A' if the subject of 'B' is not exist in 'A'.

### This result is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the below formula in spreadsheet B which contains 5000 rows,

`=IFERROR(INDEX(SheetA!$A:$J,MATCH($A2,SheetA!$A:$A,0),COLUMN()),"")`

This is a simple `INDEX` - `MATCH` formula which looks up values in `SheetA` matches it with `SheetB` and prints output in `SheetB`. Use the formula in `SheetB` cell `B2`.

Explanation:

- `A2` cell in `SheetB` is matched with `A:A` in `SheetA`.
- If found, pulls all the column data of that item from A:J from `SheetA`.

Once you pasted the formula in B2, drag it across all required columns. Then drag the same across all rows or just double click the fill handle, so that the formula is filled for all 5000 rows and data is pulled.

Let me know if you face any difficulties. Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: there was something happened which is: some empty cells in sheet A is transferred to sheet B as follow: '0' if it is a number column,  '00-jan-00' if it is a date column, '0:00' if it is a time column. ????? how can I keep it empty as sheet A?

Comment: @alaa are you sure those are empty cells in sheet A? if so they wont be updated in sheet B as 0. If you still find a problem add an IF condition to update space if the returned number is 0.

Comment: Yes I am sure they are empty cells in sheet A. Can I use your formula in some way like 'paste special (value)'?

Comment: @alaa  Can you update the image here with the error, or share the sheet in a link. Let me see if i can help

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to Macros I don't think what you want to achieve is possible, however it is possible to get something very close.  The core issue is that a function cannot create rows so you have to start with the number you want to end up with.

I my proposal you end up with a 3 Book solution.  Book A with 500 rows, Book B with 2,000 rows, and Book C which is the result also with 2,000 rows but many of them blank.

You would start by creating Book C with a complete list of IDs from Book B i.e. all 2,000 of them.  This could be a copy and paste or you could assign them using the Excel `=` function.  For this example put them into column "A".

Next we want data to appear only if it is in Book A.  We do the lookup using `VLOOKUP()` and if the data is missing we get a `#N/A` error.

So before things get complex in column B of the new Book add the formula:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,[BookA]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$200,1,FALSE)),"row missing","row there")`

This will return a text message indicating if the row exists in Book A and will be used as a flag to display the remainder of the data.

Check this works and if it does change it to:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,[BookA]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$200,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)`

We now want to get column B, C, D etc. from Book A based upon the True/False flag we have created.  So column C in the new sheet is something like:

`=IF($B1,[BookA]Sheet1!B1,"")`

If you have the `$` signs in the right places is should copy and paste nicely.

You have 2 options for improving this and getting nearer your objective.

1. Embed the initial lookup in the 2nd IF statement
2. Use conditional formatting to turn the text white if it should not be there (including the ID)

I have not done either of these because it is un-readable and is basically write once code that you can never modify without starting again.

Good luck.

Comment: can u explain in details? I want the steps to understand what u say Thanks.

Comment: I want to insert empty rows in my spreadsheet to match the rows order in the external sheet

Comment: I am now not sure of the problem / question.  Without Macros there is no way to add rows to a sheet.  You have to start off with all of the rows.  You can then bring data in.So if you want 5,000 rows in the result you need to start with 5,000 rows.  You can then bring data in (using VLOOKUP) to populate the rows that match.  Have I got the right problem here?

Comment: Yes you got it.

Comment: Sorry to be slow here but can I just get this 100%.  You currently have sheet "A" with 500 rows (with IDs).  Sheet "B" has 5,000 rows (with IDs).  You want to end up with a sheet with 5,000 rows, and with 500 of them highlighted and with extra information?